# SWF to HTML5 or iPad compatible format

Tags: ipad, html, flash

Is there any SWF to HTML5 converter or any format which can run on the ipad? not smokescreen... other alternatives.......? 
 THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly convert SWF to HTML5.  There is not a straightforward 1-to-1 relationship at all.  They are completely different beasts.  Depending on what is in your SWF, you may be able to rebuild it with HTML5 and Javascript, but you haven't listed what your project does.

Comment: Swiffy does more close a job then I have seen. There are terrible chunks of code to place and lots of big JS kb files but it does the main SWF conversion job.

Answer (score 0):

I think Adobe's packager for Iphone (http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/packagerforiphone/) is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this now!

http://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/

Shame they wont release this as desktop software!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly convert swf to gaf file with GAF converter. GAF consists of texture atlas and config file. Also on its site you can download Cocos2d-x, Starling and Unity3d libraries to play your animations on ipad then.